# Can't edit custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I'm using the following code to create two custom post types:

[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/gK6LnBcU)

The Spotlight custom post type is giving me the edit/permalink to edit the post. However, the cooking video isn't. I've just copied the code from the Spotlights, changed the pertinent info for Cooking Videos so I don't get why it isn't working.

Comment: Where are you looking for the edit link - admin area or frontend?

Comment: The dashboard admin area.

Comment: I just put your code into my functions.php, and I get everything as expected - the permalink shows up as soon as a draft is saved, I can edit, etc.  I ran into an issue like this, and tracked it down to Advanced Access Manager, so maybe turn off all your plugins and test from there?

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was working previously and it didn't make sense that one was working and the other wasn't.

On edit:
I just tried turning off all plugins and that didn't make the permalink links appear.

Comment: Hmmm - so even after saving a post (as draft or publish) it's not showing?  Try switching to the default theme (putting your code into `functions.php` of course).  Maybe try turning on the 'slug' metabox?  I don't think that would affect anything, but stranger things have happened.

Comment: I found the problem with the help of one of our IT guys. It just so happens WP didn't like how I registered my post type (naming convention). I was using cookingVideo but once it was changed to all lower case in the function.php file and the DB, everything worked fine. Thanks for the help SickHippie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told SickHippie in the comment, this was a matter of the naming convention while registering the custom post type in the functions.php file. I used camel-case and the DB didn't like that. Once it was changed to all lower-case, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You've given both the same menu position, so you'll need to change one to something else.

```
 'menu_position' => 20,
```

Comment: Not so - in this instance, `'menu_position' => 20,` simply means "Below Pages".

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the same array where you set public and menu position.

```
'show_in_menu' => true,
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't seem to work.